# Cross Table Color By Column Comparison

Tags: color-scheme, spotfire

Using a cross table I would like to color cells in Column A based on its value compared to the corresponding cell value in Column B. I can find references to coloring based on set values, but this needs to be dynamic based on the second column.

Basically, if A1 is >= B1, then color A1 Green; if A1 is < B1, then color A1 Red.  Additionally, I'd like to declare if B2 is blank, then color A1 Grey (or not at all - I just don't want A1 to be Green (or red) if B1 is blank).

I've tried using the Boolean option, but can't see how to include the column to column comparison. Any suggestions?

I did find how this can be done within a data table, but the cross table provides the flexibility I need for the data being displayed.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I tried and usig Axis.Color it is possible to give different color based on the value of particular column but didnt find the way to make it dependant on relations between columns.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'm finding the same obstacle.  One of those "there's gotta be a way!" scenarios!